# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when combining data elements

Tags: python

I am fairly new to the world of python and I am facing an issue where `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` is being thrown.

My code is here:

```
def combine_via_columns(element):
     if(element[0:6] != 'N/A'):
         element[1]=element[1]+","+element[2]+","+element[3]+","+element[4]
         return element
     else:
         logger.error("N/A value not permitted...")
```

In short, if the values inside of element are not 'N/A' I am attempting to put all values into position one, seperated by commas. The code achives what I want (at least it is when I am running my unit tests) but I am facing the `TypeError`. If anyone could help here, that would be much appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide further details.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of your expected input and output?

Comment: Apparently `element == None` from the caller of your function and you do not handle that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably running your code something like this (effectively):

```py
def combine_via_columns(element):
    if(element[0:6] != 'N/A'):
        element[1]=element[1]+","+element[2]+","+element[3]+","+element[4]
        return element
    else:
        logger.error("N/A value not permitted...")

element = None
x = combine_via_columns(element)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
    if(element[0:6] != 'N/A'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

If you were to change it to this, for example, it would work better:

```py
def combine_via_columns(element):
    if(element[0:6] != 'N/A'):
        element[1]=element[1]+","+element[2]+","+element[3]+","+element[4]
        return element
    else:
        logger.error("N/A value not permitted...")

element = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6']
x = combine_via_columns(element)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['0', '1,2,3,4', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't handling cases where `element == None`. Moving to a try/except block and logging the `Nones` should help to remedy this:

```
def combine_via_columns(element):
    try:
        if(element[0:6] != 'N/A'):
            element[1] = element[1] + "," + element[2] + "," + element[3] + "," + element[4]
            return element
        else:
            logger.error("N/A value not permitted...")

    except TypeError:
        logger.error("None value not premitted...")
```

Alternatively, you could add a check for `NoneType` at the beginning of the function.